# Can I use spark-submit to run an application who doesn't run spark jobs immediately but waits for callers doing REST requests to start them?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-spark

I have an application bundled with `Apache Spark 2.4.4` for dependency and made executable through a `spring-boot-maven-plugin` that creates an uber-jar of 192 MB :

```xml
<build>
    <finalName>application-metier-et-gestion</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Accompagnied by an `application.properties` that configures *Spark* and others tools,

```
# Serveur web.
server.port=9090

temp.dir=/data/tmp

# Spark
spark.app.name=Config metier-et-gestion
spark.home=.
master.uri=local[6]
spark.driver.memory=4g

# Base de données PostGis
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/comptesfrance 
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.datasource.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:/db/changelog/compte-france-postgis-changelog.xml
```

the application starts through a simple main function,

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
   }
}
```

and eventually waits for requests coming from REST callers to serve them, using *Spark* jobs to produce their expected results.

```java
/**
 * Services REST des comptes des communes. 
 */
@RestController
@Api(value="Comptes des communes (balance et individuels)")
public class ComptesCommunesController {
   /** Service d'acquisition des comptes de comptabilité. */
   @Autowired
   private BalanceCompteService balanceCompteService; 

   /** Session Spark. */
   @Autowired
   private SparkSession session;

   /**
    * Renvoyer les comptes d'une commune.
    * @param anneeCOG Année du code officiel géograhique de référence.
    * @param annee Année recherchée.
    * @param codeCommune Code de la commune.
    * @return Liste de ses comptes.
    * @throws TechniqueException si un incident survient.
    */
   @RequestMapping("/comptes/commune/codeCommune")

   @ApiOperation(value = "Retourne les comptes M14 d'une commune", response=List.class)
   @ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Liste des comptes de la commune obtenus.")
      }
   )   
   public List<Compte> obtenirComptesParCodeCommune(
         @ApiParam(name = "anneeCOG", value = "Année du Code Officiel Géographique.", example = "2019")
         @RequestParam(name="anneeCOG") int anneeCOG,

         @ApiParam(name = "annee", value = "Année de la balance des comptes M14 à extraire.", example = "2018")
         @RequestParam(name="annee") int annee,

         @ApiParam(name = "codeCommune", value = "Code de la commune dont on veut les comptes.", example = "29046")
         @RequestParam(name="codeCommune") String codeCommune) throws TechniqueException {
      Objects.requireNonNull(codeCommune, "Le numéro de commune ne peut pas valoir null.");
      List<Compte> comptes = this.balanceCompteService.obtenirComptes(this.session, anneeCOG, annee, new CodeCommune(codeCommune));
      return comptes;
   }

   /**
    * Renvoyer les comptes d'une commune.
    * @param anneeCOG Année du code officiel géograhique de référence.
    * @param annee Année recherchée.
    * @param numeroCompte Numéro de compte.
    * @return Liste de ses comptes.
    * @throws TechniqueException si un incident survient.
    */
   @RequestMapping("/comptes/commune/numeroCompte")
   @ApiOperation(value = "Retourne la valeur d'un compte M14 pour toutes les communes qui ont ce compte")
   public List<Compte> obtenirComptesParNumeroCompte(
         @ApiParam(name = "anneeCOG", value = "Année du Code Officiel Géographique.", example = "2019")
         @RequestParam(name="anneeCOG") int anneeCOG, 

         @ApiParam(name = "annee", value = "Année de la balance des comptes M14 à extraire.", example = "2018")
         @RequestParam(name="annee") int annee,

         @ApiParam(name = "numeroCompte", value = "Numéro du compte que l'on veut rechercher dans toutes les communes.", example = "1321")
         @RequestParam(name="numeroCompte") String numeroCompte) throws TechniqueException {
      Objects.requireNonNull(numeroCompte, "Le numéro de compte ne peut pas valoir null.");
      List<Compte> comptes = this.balanceCompteService.obtenirComptes(this.session, anneeCOG, annee, new NumeroCompte(numeroCompte));
      return comptes;
   }
}
```

This application is working well, this way. But for many reasons, bundling it with an embedded `Apache Spark` causes me some troubles. I would better like using an external *Spark* instance, unzipped/installed by someone else, where my application would only plug into. In my mind, I would then compile it with *Spark* dependencies in *provided* scope.

But if I do that, I'll have let's say, an uber-jar of 130 MB only, but how will I run it with the existing `Apache Spark` on the computer where I will deliver it ?

- Will `spark-submit` accept to start a class that will not run a *Spark* job immediately and return a result like classical *SparkPi* examples do, but only wait for later calls ?
- Is `spark-class` a command that could else offer a solution ?

I don't know if I can engage myself in this way, or if it is doomed to fail. If it is a clever idea or not.

Comment: The apache livy project might fit your needs.

https://livy.incubator.apache.org/

Comment: @Mayank : yes, it can be a way. I happy to see that for each problem it seems to exist always a solution available. But it is an incubator project of version 0.60... And I have also to add `Apache Zeppelin`, incubator 0.82... And whatever, a Spark cluster (or local) shall be deployed first, and my problem is still the same : I don't know how do deploy an `Apache Spark` alone, a way that it starts without attempting to complete a Spark job immediately.